# How to print out multiples lines of text in a row (one next to the other) in Python

Tags: python, text

So if I got for example:

```
print("some text\n
    some more text\n
    yet some more text")
```

and:

```
print("another some text\n
    another some more text\n
    yet another some more text")
```

How can print them next to each other without doing this:

```
print("some text         another some text\n
    some more text       another some more text\n
    yet some more text   yet another some more text")
```

I don't want to do what I just showed you, because I'll be generating more of this columns with different text and values, but I want them next to each other with the `\n` breaks.

How can I do that in Python?

Comment: You could create 2 lists and loop over them

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to go on about this is to loop over the lists of strings like so :

```
column_1 = ["some text", "some more text", "yet some more text"]
column_2 = ["another some text", "another some more text", "yet another some more text"]

for i in range(0, len(column_1 )):
    print("{}\t{}".format(column_1[i], column_2[i]))
```

If the length of both columns is the same of course. You could be more crafty with the tabbing if you want to align them better.

Comment: That would word if I had 2 columns, but what if I have 3? or 4? or 5? Of course I could add more {} but they'll appear as {} if there's no other columns.

Comment: Well I don't know your full situation but to add 1 more column is a matter of defining it and adding it in the loop `print("{}\t{}\t{}".format(column_1[i], column_2[i], column_3[i]))`. If you have lots of lists, you can make a list of lists and loop over those in the same style. All depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for, there's something that you write like: (end="") or something but It only works for single lines :/

Answer (score 0):

```
string1 = 'this is a\n string with\n line breaks'
string2 = ' beautiful\n some\n end'

stringcombined = ''.join(list(sum(list(zip(string1.split('\n'), ['\t'+i+'\n' for i in string2.split('\n')])), ()))).replace('\n ','\n')

print(stringcombined)
```

Output:

```
this is a     beautiful
string with   some
line breaks   end
```

Edit:

```
stringcombined = ''.join(list(sum(list(zip([i+'\n' for i in string1.split('\n')], [i+'\n' for i in string2.split('\n')])), ()))).replace('\n ','\n')
```

Output:

```
this is a
beautiful
string with
some
line breaks
end
```

Edit2:

For a third column just add it inside `zip`

```
string3 = '#\n#\n#'
stringcombined = ''.join(list(sum(list(zip([i+'\n' for i in string1.split('\n')], [i+'\n' for i in string2.split('\n')], [i+'\n' for i in string3.split('\n')])), ()))).replace('\n ','\n')
```

Output:

```
this is a
beautiful
#
string with
some
#
line breaks
end
#
```

Comment: yeah but the thing is that I want to keep the breaks on the strings, I jus want them with the breaks next to each other (string1 with breaks + string2 + breaks next to each other)

Comment: see edit. is that they way you want it? I also added tabs in the first option.

Comment: what if I had a third column

Comment: and 4th one and 5th one and so on, the u would say - add those strings too, and what if I don't have them but I add them anyways. It would give me an error

Comment: see edit2, maybe you should be more specific in your question

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into this example:

```
a = ["some text", 'some more text', 'yet some more text']
b = ["another some text", "another some more text", "yet another some more text"]
c = ["third text 1", "third text 2", "third text 3"]

print('\n'.join(a))
print('\n'.join(b))

# COMBINED MAGIC:
print('\n'.join(map(lambda x: ('{:30}'*len(x)).format(*x).strip(), zip(a, b, c))))
```

First two prints are equal to yours. As for the last one step-by-step:

1. zip N ( in this case N = 3 ) lists with strings into single one where each element is a tuple of corresponding elements from `a`, `b`, `c` lists
2. For each tuple we create formatter template using the lenght of each tuple.
3. Pass unpacked tuple to `format` function
4. Join with newline symbol
5. Print

Output from the last print call:

```
some text                     another some text             third text 1
some more text                another some more text        third text 2
yet some more text            yet another some more text    third text 3
```